# Activex Control Equivalent control on edge to open MS word docs and edit them

Tags: ms-word, activex, microsoft-edge

I work on a web Application which runs only on IE11. Currently, we use ActiveX control to open Documents (MS word) with in the web application. so far, everything works perfect with ActiveX control however Microsoft will stop supporting ActiveX control on IE11 in few months. 
We want to upgrade this Web Application to make it run on EDGE. as ActiveX control is no longer an option, Is there a way/any different control equivalent to ActiveX, which I can leverage on to add it as an addOn in the browser, so the users can open/edit word documents.
Thanks in advance.

Note: When i Say Editing it's basic editing like font size and insert a table at the most.

Answer (score 1):

You said **Microsoft will stop supporting ActiveX control on IE11 in few months**.

We don't have any news that Microsoft will stop supporting Activex control on IE 11. Maybe you have some misunderstanding. IE will continue to support ActiveX but it will block the outdated Activex control. So if your ActiveX control is outdated then you need to update it with the latest version to continue to make it work with IE 11 browser.

See this information:

> Because many ActiveX controls aren’t automatically updated, they can
>   become outdated as new versions are released. It’s very important that
>   you keep your ActiveX controls up-to-date because malicious software
>   (or malware) can target security flaws in outdated controls, damaging
>   your computer by collecting info from it, installing unwanted
>   software, or by letting someone else control it remotely. To help
>   avoid this situation, Internet Explorer includes a new security
>   feature, called out-of-date ActiveX control blocking. Out-of-date
>   ActiveX control blocking lets you:
>
> - Know when IE prevents a webpage from loading common, but outdated    ActiveX controls.
> - Interact with other parts of the webpage that aren’t affected by the outdated control.
> - Update the outdated control, so that it’s up-to-date and safer to use.

References:

1. [Use ActiveX controls for Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17469/windows-internet-explorer-use-activex-controls)
2. [Out-of-date ActiveX control blocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/out-of-date-activex-control-blocking)
3. [Blocked out-of-date ActiveX controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/blocked-out-of-date-activex-controls)

If you want to move to the MS Edge browser then I suggest you check the [Office browser extension.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-access-to-your-office-files-in-the-browser-dc1024b4-92be-46eb-81a7-aea85368baa0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_signin&ID0EAAGAAA=Edge)

The Office browser extension is a free extension for Edge and Chrome, that gives you easy access to your Office apps and documents anywhere on the web.  You can quickly access and edit Word, Excel, PowerPoint and other Office documents right from your Edge or Chrome browsers, without having to open your desktop apps.